# genetic algorithm optimiyation r

Tags: r, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I would like kindly to ask if anybody has an idea how to build a genetic algorithm GA model that is able to solve the "diet problem" with constraints and minimization objective in R?

thank you and appreciate your contribution

Comment: apparently not [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20genetic%20algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

I use `rgenoud` package in R. See paper here: http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/papers/rgenoudJSS.pdf

Comment: thank you very much for your answer: Now i have the following simple "diet problem", I used lpSolveAPI package, it provide a linear programming solution. For cretin objective I want to solve the problem using genetic algorithm: the problem has the following components:

Comment: It seems that you're asking an entirely separate question here. Maybe you should create a new question, and make it carefully crafted showing what you've tried so far, and where you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I solved the problem via using lpSolveAPI package linear programming. A very simple and reduced example of the problem is: Minimize Obj func c(334, 222, 266, 140)
Subject to   c(17, 52, 46, 81), ">=", 27
                  c(7, 40, 27, 58), ">=", 19
 lower  bound= c(0.20, 0.35, 0.05), columns = c(1, 2, 4))
 upper bound= c(0.35, 0.50, 0.10), columns = c(1, 2, 4))
Find the best variables (diet composition)